# How to open .NET 2.0 DotNetNuke project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dotnetnuke

Need to open old DotNetNuke project in Visual Studio 2013. 
But there is no .sln or some project file. I would be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening it as a website project, by pointing to the local url you have running in Iis

Comment: Nice. I opened it, its still not working because of too many missing modules, but i'l fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck with it, I would recommend you upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thanks. One more question - what about debug thsi project in Visual studio 2013? It does not hit my breakpoints. It's WSP model, i am attaching debug to IIS proccess, but there is no result. Checked web.config - debug="true".

Comment: First thing to check is are you attached to the proper IIS process?